# How to Cast a Single website to multiple devices using WEBRTC?

Tags: casting, webrtc

I want to create a server on one device and the changes I make on a certain website should be visible on other devices in real time, I don't want to cast the entire screen just the website.
Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want really to use WebRTC to send something that appears in a web browser to another web client, you should see [Canvas to peer connection](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/capture/canvas-pc/).

Anyway, if various clients should be informed about an event via web, I suggest that you see [Your first Web Progressive Application](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/?hl=en)